# IOS WebClip WebApp How to keep fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, web-clips

I packaged my website into a WebClip App, but I found that only the homepage can be full screen. Once I use  to jump to other pages (still this site), Safari will have toolbars and Url, and full screen will be Invalid.
This string of code has Add
`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />`
Where is the problem? Is there any way besides using iframe?

Hopefully this provides all of the necessary information needed to understand the problem